# Ruby prime numbers

Tags: ruby

So i have the following 2 program:

1st program, which works as intended( Ex: input 7, output Number is prime

```
puts "Enter a positive number: "
number = gets.chomp.to_i

prime = true
i = 2

while i <= number/2
    if number % i == 0
        prime = false
    end
    i += 1
end

if prime == true
    puts "Number is prime"
else
    puts "Number is not prime"
end
```

2nd program, which is basically the same, just added the user the ability to check for prime numbers in a range. This program only shows 2 and 3 as prime numbers(if input is 10, for example)

```
puts "Enter a positive number: "
range = gets.chomp.to_i

prime = true
i = 2
number = 2

while number <= range

    while i <= number/2

        if number % i == 0
            prime = false
        end

        i += 1
    end

    if prime == true
        puts "#{number} is prime"
    else
        puts "#{number} is not prime"
    end

    number += 1
end
```

I think the problem is with the way im incrementing, since i can't use a for, but i tried debugging and i just don't get it, it should print out 5 and 7 aswell, if i input 10 as my range of numbers.

Comment: Move the `prime = true` and `i = 2` assignments at the start of the outer loop.

Comment: Ah man, thanks, that was it.

Comment: FYI Ruby provides `Prime` for finding prime numbers.

Comment: @theBugger Isn't an essential part of being a prime that it doesn't have an integer square root? :-)

Comment: @AndreasLundgren You're right, I wrote exactly the opposite of what I wanted to. xD Of course, if a number has a real natural square root it's surely not prime. If you check for this in the code you can prevent to make a lot of maths in the first place. Thanks for pointing it, I would never noticed it =)

Comment: You are asking readers to figure out the problem that "1st program" is solving by reading through the code. That will cause many readers to skip your question. It also suggests you were to too lazy to begin the question with a verbal description of the problem, which would have been a time-saver for readers, especially because so little would have been needed: "I wish to obtain a number from a user and then determine if that number is prime."

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry if i didn't add a proper description, but even in the the title, i added the fact that this question is about prime numbers in ruby.

Comment: Suppose a co-worker ask you to look at some of their code that wasn't working correctly. Wouldn't your first question--if the answer had not already been provided--be something like, "What are you trying to do"? If the co-worker answered, "It's about arrays", would that be a satisfactory answer? My comment was intended to be constructive.